# How to make sure if I properly uninstalled my package manager in macOS

Tags: package-management, macos

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra, and I needed to download a package manager for an Octave project. I already had Docker before this. I downloaded Homebrew, MacPorts and fink not realizing I only needed one package manager. I only want Homebrew and need to correctly and fully uninstall MacPorts and fink. I think I have uninstalled fink, but I am not sure how to check. I get `sudo: port: command not found` when I type  `sudo port -fp uninstall installed` to uninstall MacPorts. I am not sure what to do here. My three questions follow.

1. How can I check if I have fully uninstalled fink and all ports?
2. How can I fully uninstall MacPorts?
3. How can I configure Homebrew and Docker so they don't mess each other up?

It was my fault for not knowing I needed just one package manager instead of three.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that brew, port, and fink have different repositories, so that it is useful (at least to me) to have them all available.

You probably also have another PM for Apple Store.

The others also store to different places:

```
brew writes to /usr/local 
fink writes to /sw 
port writes to /opt/local
```

So while I don't have an answer about how to get rid of MacPorts, my meta-answer / advice is to keep them all, unless you have a good reason not to.

This is on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Apple/BSD, Darwin 16.7.0, x86_64
Distribution        : macOS 10.12.6 (16G29), Sierra
brew - ( local: /usr/local/bin/brew, 2017-06-03 )
```

Thanks for asking the question -- it reminded me that I had not yet installed port and fink on a mac mini.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl